# Change border color of text-input

Tags: css

To remove the border of a text-input when it is active, I can do:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

How would I then add a border-color of my own on it? For example:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;/*here change the color*/
    border:1px solid red;/*here change the color*/
}
textarea:focus:hover {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;/*here change the color*/
    border:1px solid red;/*here change the color*/
    border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this **[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s8chsbzL/)**.

CSS:

```
input:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea{
  outline: 1;
  outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Check all feature of outline property : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Changes border color on focus.

```
input:focus{
    outline: 0;
    border:1px solid #0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant property to change is `border`, `outline` has no effect.

Please see below:

```css
textarea, input {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="text" value="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

On focus, I recommend to use the `outline` and/or `text-shadow` properties. I you use **Modernizr** you can use both, so old browsers that do not support the `text-shadow` can have on focus effect.

```css
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px red;
}

.no-boxshadow textarea:focus, .no-boxshadow input:focus {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea><br />
```

I you prefer to use the `borders` instead, I recommend you to specify a default border styling on your element, to avoid a flick effect on focus.